# Fake Chrome Window's Size While Keeping It Maximized

Tags: google-chrome

Not sure if this makes any sense...
I like to use my browser (Chrome) for a few apps like Spotify and Discord Web; my issue is that I like to have Chrome's Window maximized and that makes (e.g.) "reading" a bit difficult because you can't have a classic 80 (or something) column width.

So, is there some workaround/extension to fake a smaller window size and keep websites' content centered, while still having Chrome maximized?
I tried using "Stylish" extension and mess around with Discord's CSS but some things are breaking when doing what I'd like to.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it might be a good feature request for a browser... it is annoying to resize the whole window for just one tab. It might be applicable to security too, since your window & screen size is another datapoint used for tracking

Comment: can you post some pictures? .... observed and desired

Comment: You can kind of do this. See if this will do what you want. In chrome, press F12 key, then click this icon: https://i.imgur.com/buX4isj.png then at the top, it will let you choose the pixel size in the window. It  may be a partial solution. You can expand the columns to wahtever you want while still keeping the window maxxed

Comment: @Narzard You're right, that's exactly what I'm looking for but without opening Developer Tools!